# Always show comment highlights in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

To comment on text in Word, I highlight the text, click add comment, type a comment, etc. When I go to print, the commented text is highlighted. When I mouse over the comment, the commented text is highlighted. Is there a way to always show the highlights on commented text, even when I'm not mousing over or printing?

Comment: http://libroediting.com/2012/10/03/track-changes-2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `Review` tab, go to the `Tracking` section.
There, you'll see a drop-down menu. It probably says `Simple Markup`. Change it to `All Markup`, and you'll see the commented sections highlighted.

Here is the official Microsoft explanation.
http://blogs.office.com/2012/08/28/comments-and-revisions-in-word-2013/

Screen (in German):
[image: Position of dropdown to always show comment background]

Detail (in English):
                                                [image: (dropdown set to "Simple Markup"]